# How can I consistently detect browser support for HTML5 search inputs?

Tags: html, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10, html-input, browser-feature-detection

I have a search input on an HTML 5 page that I need to work in multiple browsers:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="type here..." />
```

I detect whether the browser supports search by seeing whether the browser rendered it as a `search` input or a regular `text` one:

```
var supportsHtml5Search = !!(inputDomElement.type !== 'text');
if (supportsHtml5Search) {
    inputDomElement.addEventListener('search', searchFunction);
}
else {
    // This browser doesn't support onsearch event, so handle keyup instead
    inputDomElement.addEventListener('keyup', searchFunction);
}
```

This worked fine - Chrome and Safari used the `onsearch` event (which also helpfully fires when they hit the clear `X` icon) and IE used the `keyup` event (with some additional checks not shown here).

However that seems to be broken in IE10, which displays a `search` exactly the same as an `<input type="text" />` (like IE9 and below) and returns `search` as the type (like Chrome/Webkit), but doesn't fire the `onsearch` event.

Is there a better way to detect search input support?

What is the best way to sniff for this feature's support?

Comment: @raina77ow that works! I changed it to `var supportsHtml5Search = !!('onsearch' in inputDomElement);` and that returns `false` in IE10 and `true` in Webkit. I've still got some testing to do, but stick it in an answer and I'll accept it :-)

Comment: Ok, done it (adding some research as well). Still wonder why do you need `!!` here - doesn't `in` always return a `boolean`?

Comment: @raina77ow I don't, the code base has a lot of bool-ish values and so it's littered with `!!` :-S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/) describes quite a robust way of detecting the event support itself - as your case is yet another one when it's different from the feature support.

Basically, one has to test a corresponding property (`onsearch` for `search` event, for example) of the corresponding elements. Like...

```
'onsearch' in document.documentElement; // true in Chrome, false in Firefox/Opera
```

It's noted in the article that Firefox will fail the check if it's done on the wrong element, but I actually found only Opera behaving that way:

```
'onchange' in document.documentElement; // false in Opera, true in Firefox/Chrome
'onchange' in document.createElement('input'); // true in Opera too
```

As a final resort, one can attempt to assign a handler for this element, then check this property again:

```
var el = document.createElement('input'); 
el.setAttribute('onsearch', 'return;'); 
typeof el.onsearch; // 'function' in Chrome, 'undefined' in Firefox/Opera
```

Comment: Do you know if anything changed in the last 5 years? I mean, if the answer is up to date or if there is a duplicate with more answers or if we need to put a bounty on this question :)

Comment: Not sure what do you mean, sorry. Apparently, there's little change in how IE10 treats things (and question was mostly about that browser). Both Chrome and Firefox are mostly consistent, but sometimes there's still a difference between 'supported' and 'working', unfortunately.